# Query of all pages, including children, ordered by meta key

Tags: wp-query

I'm saving a revised date as `meta_value` on every page and I want to display them ordered by the date in a list in my plugin screen.

How to both include child pages (can be 4-6 levels deep) in the query result and at the same time order by the `meta_value`? This is since `get_pages` can't order by a `meta_value` from my understanding and I can't seem to include child pages in any other query, such as `wp_query` or `get_posts()`.

This is what I have using `get_pages` but it doesn't work:

```
$pages = get_pages( array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'meta_key'    => 'review_date',
    'meta_key'    => 'reviewed_by_user_id',
    'sort_column' => 'review_date',
    'sort_order'  => 'asc'
) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing since i found no other way

```
//Fetch all pages
$pages = get_pages( array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'meta_key' => 'review_date',
        //'meta_key' => 'reviewed_by_user_id',
        'sort_column' => 'review_date',
        'sort_order' => 'asc'
        ));

//Fetch metadata for each page
$ordered_pages = array();
foreach ($pages as $page)
{
    $metadata = get_metadata('post', $page->ID);
    $user = $metadata['reviewed_by_user_id'][0];
    $date = $metadata['review_date'][0];

    array_push($ordered_pages, array(
        'ID' => $page->ID,
        'title' => $page->post_title,
        'review_date' => $date,
        'reviewed_by_user_id' => $user,
        'link' => get_edit_post_link($page->ID),
        ));
}

//Order the pages 
$orderby_array = array();
foreach ($ordered_pages as $key => $row)
{
    $orderby_array[$key] = $row[$orderby];
}
array_multisort($orderby_array, SORT_DESC, $ordered_pages);
```

and then looping trough the pages like this

```
foreach ($ordered_pages as $page)
{
   //Some code
}
```

Its not pretty and it generates lot of extra db calls with the get_metadata call but since its a rarely viewed page in admin it's ok for me.